# Javascript Canvas - Draw Line not drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having trouble with a Javascript game I'm writing.  I have an HTML canvas which I am drawing on with Javascript.

I am trying to recreate an airport, so I have drawn some runways (rectangles) and also drawn a waypoint (also a rectangle) that sits `x` amount of pixels from the arrival end of the runway.  I want to draw a line connecting the runway and the waypoint.

My code to do so is below.  Note that my runways are stored in an array of `Runway` objects, where `topLeft` is the top left corner of the runway, with an x and y value, `wayPointTopLeft` is the top left corner of the associated waypoint, also with an x and y value, `wayPointWidthHeight` is the width/height of my waypoint rectangle shape (which is drawn as a square).

```
for (i = 0; i < aRunways.length; i++) {
        // Runway
        ctx.fillStyle = clone(colourBrightGreen);
        ctx.lineWidth=1;
        ctx.rect(aRunways[i].topLeft.x,aRunways[i].topLeft.y,aRunways[i].width,aRunways[i].height);
        ctx.fill();

        // Waypoint
        if(aRunways[i].name == "25") {
            console.log(aRunways[i].topLeft.y + (aRunways[i].height / 2));
            console.log(aRunways[i].wayPointTopLeft.y + (aRunways[i].wayPointWidthHeight / 2));
        }

        ctx.rect(aRunways[i].wayPointTopLeft.x, aRunways[i].wayPointTopLeft.y, aRunways[i].wayPointWidthHeight, aRunways[i].wayPointWidthHeight);
        ctx.strokeStyle = colourBrightGreen;
        ctx.lineWidth=4;
        ctx.stroke();

        // Name
        var textX = 0;
        var textY = 0;

        ctx.font = "12px Arial";        
        textX = aRunways[i].wayPointTopLeft.x + (aRunways[i].wayPointWidthHeight / 2) - (getTextWidth(aRunways[i].name, ctx.font) / 2);
        textY = (aRunways[i].wayPointTopLeft.y + aRunways[i].wayPointWidthHeight + 17);
        ctx.fillStyle = clone(colourBrightGreen);

        ctx.fillText(aRunways[i].name, textX, textY);   

        // Line
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = clone(colourBrightGreen);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo((aRunways[i].topLeft.x + (aRunways[i].width / 2)), (aRunways[i].topLeft.y + (aRunways[i].height / 2)));
        ctx.lineTo((aRunways[i].wayPointTopLeft.x + (aRunways[i].wayPointWidthHeight / 2)), (aRunways[i].wayPointTopLeft.y + (aRunways[i].wayPointWidthHeight / 2)));
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

This works fine for vertically oriented runways, but I have a horizontal runway and the line isn't being drawn.  This is what is being drawn:
[image: Output]

You'll notice I have some code to check if the runway name is `25`.  This is my horizontal runway.  The values outputted in the console for the two y values I'm testing is 292.5, which makes sense, they should both be the same seeing as its a horizontal line.  If I change those console log lines to output the associated x values, I get `313` for the runway's x value and `395.5` for the waypoint.  Again, this is correct.

Why is it that I can't draw a line from (313, 292.5) to (395.5, 292.5)?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your final line, use `.stroke()` instead of `.closePath()` and `.fill()`

It looks from here like you're creating a degenerate empty box, and then asking for it to be filled, when you should just be drawing a line.